# Circumvent the App Store to install Fortnite on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, games

Is there another way *besides* the Mac App Store to get Fortnite installed?

While I haven't played it yet, I am interested in trying it. I understand it is free to play, and items like player skins can be bought in-game. So I'm wondering why Epic needed Apple's App Store distribution channel to begin with, but is it available for download by other means (maybe Steam, .dmg download, etc)?

Sorry if I'm asking something obvious to most gamers here. I didn't see a way to download an installer from [Epic's site](https://www.epicgames.com). Thanks.

Comment: Fortnite has never been on the Mac App Store, as there's no requirement to sell apps on Mac via the MAS.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I assumed that being a shooter, it was (at least primarily) a desktop and console game. And by that extrapolation when I read about [Apple removing it](https://www.wired.com/story/epic-games-sues-apple-fortnite-app-store/) that it was from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download Fortnite directly from [Epic Game's Fortnite website](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/download).

You may need to sign-up and log-in before downloading. The download is a `.dmg` file.